# Do there exist shorter ways of solving for $x$ (or other smarter methods)?

Tags: numerical-methods, radicals, square-numbers, nested-radicals, radical-equations

> > **Problem:**
>
> If$$\frac 13\Bigr(\sqrt [3] {6\big(9+5\sqrt{3}\big)}+\sqrt [3] {6\big(9-5\sqrt{3}\big)}\Bigr)=2,\tag1$$ then $$\sqrt [3] {\frac x9}\bigr(\sqrt [3] {9+5\sqrt{3}}+\sqrt [3] {9-5\sqrt{3}}\bigr)=2.\tag2$$Prove Eq. $(1)$ and then solve for $x$ in Eq. $(2)$.

I made up this problem. I discovered the first formula, inspired by how $\sqrt [3]{2+\sqrt{5}}+\sqrt [3]{2-\sqrt{5}}=1$. And then I took out the six and with some trial and error, I found $x$ (because $x\div 9$ is a familiar fraction). My question is, however, how does one solve equations like these in a shorter amount of time? Are there any techniques I should know?

---

**My Attempt Regarding Solution for $x$:**

If Eq. $(1)$ is true, then $$\sqrt [3]{6\big(9+5\sqrt{3}\big)}+\sqrt [3]{6\big(9-5\sqrt{3}\big)}=2\times 3 = 6.$$ Now I think one can do the following, but I am not too sure. $$\begin{align}6&=\sqrt [3]{6\big(9+5\sqrt{3}\big)}+\sqrt [3]{6\big(9-5\sqrt{3}\big)} \\ &= \sqrt[3]6\sqrt[3]{9+5\sqrt{3}}+\sqrt [3]6\sqrt[3]{9-5\sqrt3} \\ &= \sqrt[3]6\bigr(\sqrt[3]{9+5\sqrt 3}+\sqrt[3]{9-5\sqrt 3}\bigr).\end{align}$$ It follows, then, that $$\begin{align}6&=\sqrt [3] 6\bigg(\frac{2}{\sqrt [3] x\div \sqrt [3] 9}\bigg) \\ &=2\sqrt[3]6 \sqrt[3]{\frac 9x}.\end{align}\tag{$\ast$}$$ Now notice that $6=\sqrt [3] 6^3$ thus $6\div \sqrt[3]6=\sqrt[3]6^2=\sqrt[3]{6^2}=\sqrt[3]{36}$. $$\therefore \sqrt [3] {36}=2\sqrt [3]{\frac 9x}\tag{$\ast\ast$}$$ which from $(\ast)$ is equivalent to the following: $$\sqrt [3]{4x}=2\tag*{$\because 36\div 9=4$}.$$ Now that I only have *one* cube, I can finally get rid of it by cubing both sides (because I know that $(\sqrt[3]a+\sqrt[3]b)^3$ does not get rid of all the cubes), id est $$\begin{align}4x&=2^3=8 \\ \therefore x&=8\div 4 = 2.\end{align}$$

I believe in both equations $(\ast)$ and $(\ast\ast)$, I could have cubed both sides, but I wanted to use as minimal steps as I could, so I tried nailing down to just one simple cube root before cubing the equation.

What I do *not* believe is that I proved Eq $(1)$. I do not think I proved it... but solving for $x$ to find that $x=2$, if we substitute that back in, it follows that Eq. $(2)$ is correct *and thus Eq. $(1)$ is correct*. But does this *actually* prove Eq. $(1)$? What if I was unaware of Eq. $(2)$? My attempt is as follows:

---

**My Attempt Regarding Proof of Eq. $(1)$:**

I got that $$\begin{align} 36&= \big(\sqrt [3]{9+5\sqrt 3}+\sqrt [3]{9-5\sqrt{3}}\big)^3 \\ &= 9+5\sqrt{3}+9-5\sqrt{3}+3\sqrt[3]{(9+5\sqrt{3})}\sqrt [3]{(9-5\sqrt{3})}\bigr(\sqrt [3]{9+5\sqrt 3}+\sqrt [3]{9-5\sqrt{3}}\bigr) \\ &= 9\require{\cancel}\cancel{+\,5\sqrt{3}}+9\cancel{-\,5\sqrt{3}}+3\sqrt[3]{(9+5\sqrt{3})(9-5\sqrt{3})}\sqrt[3] {36} \\ &= 9+9+3\sqrt [3]{36(9+5\sqrt 3)(9-5\sqrt 3)}\\ &= 18+3\sqrt [3]{36\bigr(9^2-(5\sqrt 3)^2\bigr)}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\binom{\because (a+b)(a-b)}{= a^2-b^2}\\ &= 18+3\sqrt [3]{36(81-25\times 3)} \\ &= 18+3\sqrt[3]{36(81-75)} \\ &= 18+3\sqrt [3]{36\times 6} \\ &= 18+3\times 6\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\bigr(\because 36=6^2\Rightarrow 36\times 6 = 6^2\times 6 = 6^3\bigr) \\ &= 18 + 18 \\ &= 36.\;\color{green}{\checkmark}\end{align}$$ I used the formula $(a+b)^3=a^3+b^3+3ab(a+b)$ and substituted $a=\sqrt[3]{9+5\sqrt{3}}$ and $b=\sqrt[3]{9-5\sqrt{3}}$. Then, I simplified (id est combined like radicals, cancelled out terms, etcetera).

I now believe I did just fine, but this was tiring. Is there a shorter way of solving such equations? Are there any smarter ways of carrying out these attempts of mine?

---

Thank you in advance (and apoligies for the long post).

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit yes. woops, my bad. thanks for the pickup. (How did I not notice??)

Comment: Denesting radicals is tricky business. However, when you're convinced that those cube roots cancel nicely, then you can believe that $6(9\pm 5\sqrt{3})$ must be a perfect cube, say, of $p + q \sqrt{3}$, where $p$ and $q$ are "nice" (ideally, *integers*). So, compare $$(p+q\sqrt{3})^3 = p^3 + 3 p^2 q \sqrt{3} + 3 p \cdot 3 q^2 + q^3 \cdot 3 \sqrt{3}$$ to $54 \pm 30 \sqrt{3}$ to get the system $$ p (p^2 + 9 q^2 ) = 54 \qquad q ( p^2 + q^2 ) = \pm10$$ If you're lucky, you see that $p=3$, $q=\pm1$ provides a solution, and you go from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a = \sqrt[3]{6(9+5\sqrt{3})}$ and $b=\sqrt[3]{6(9-5\sqrt{3})}$ then:

$$\require{cancel}
a^3+b^3 = 6\cdot\left(9+\bcancel{5\sqrt{3}}\right) + 6 \cdot\left(9-\bcancel{5\sqrt{3}}\right) = 108 \\[10px]
a b = \sqrt[3]{6^2 \cdot\left(9+5\sqrt{3}\right)\cdot\left(9-5\sqrt{3}\right)} = \sqrt[3]{6^2\cdot(9^2 - 5^2 \cdot 3)} = \sqrt[3]{6^2\cdot 6} = 6
$$

It follows that $\,(a+b)^3 = a^3+b^3+3ab(a+b)=108+18(a+b)\,$, so $\,t = a+b\,$ is a root of $\,t^3 - 18t - 108=0\,$. The latter cubic has the [easy-to-find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) rational root $\,t=6\,$, and it is straightforward to show that that's the only real root, which concludes the proof of $(1)$.

Comment: I love your method, but unfortunately I cannot upvote (I have reached my daily voting limit) and have to wait $22$ hours before I can upvote. Nonetheless, congratulations! $$\color{green}{\checkmark}$$

Comment: @user477343 Thanks. You had it figured out essentially, including the simplification of the product of radicals, and the binomial cube expansion. All that was left was to put everything in the right sequence as to make it a proof.

Answer (score 2):

Let
\begin{eqnarray*}
y=\sqrt [3] {6\big(9+5\sqrt{3}\big)}+\sqrt [3] {6\big(9-5\sqrt{3})},
\end{eqnarray*}
cube this and we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
y^3=108+3y \sqrt [3]  {6\big(9+5\sqrt{3}\big)}\sqrt [3] {6\big(9-5\sqrt{3})}=18y+108.
\end{eqnarray*}
This factorises $(y-6)(y^2+6x-18)=0$ so $y=6$, confirming the first equation.

The second equation gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \sqrt [3] { \frac{x}{9}} =\frac{ \sqrt[3]{6}}{3} =\frac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{\sqrt[3]{9}}
\end{eqnarray*}
So we have $x=2$ as required.

Comment: I liked your answer (factorising makes it much easier), but the answer above introduced me to the **Rational Root Theorem**. I will upvote tomorrow because I have reached my daily voting limit (have to wait $22$ hours before I can vote again).